# Disable event creation on Weekends

Tags: fullcalendar, ui-calendar, fullcalendar-2

I am trying to use Fullcalendar for one of my leave application. I have select option enabled so that the user can select dates and apply leave on it. But I want to disable weekends from getting selected, ie it should give a alert when the user clicks on the weekends. Is it achivable?

My code

```js
this.calendarOptions = {
    height:450,
    defaultDate: moment(new Date(),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    editable: false,
    stick:true,
    selectable:true,
    eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: this.eventList,
    header: {
        left: 'month basicWeek basicDay',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    displayEventTime: false,

    select: (start, end, allDay) => {
        this.startDate=moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        this.endDate=moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD");   
        $('.first.modal').modal('show');
    },
    dayRender: (date, cell)=> {
    //logic
    },
    selectOverlap:false,
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that on the `select` method. Just go from the startDate to the endDate and check if any of those days are weekends. 
If so, display the alert / popup and return false.

```js
select: (start, end, allDay) => {
    var startDate = moment(start),
    endDate = moment(end),
    date = startDate.clone(),
    isWeekend = false;

    while (date.isBefore(endDate)) {
        if (date.isoWeekday() == 6 || date.isoWeekday() == 7) {
            isWeekend = true;
        }    
        date.add(1, 'day');
    }

    if (isWeekend) {
        alert('can\'t add event - weekend');

        return false;
    }

    this.startDate= startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    this.endDate= endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");   

    //$('.first.modal').modal('show');
},
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/dnpky5cL/1/).