# FullCalendar - Block drag and drop on new event creation

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a question about drag and drop with the FullCalendar pluguin. I'm working in a web project and I need to limit the use of some functions, such as limiting the scheduling time and I need to disable the drag-and-drop feature when the new event is created. I read the documentation on the site and I did not quite understand how to do it. Any idea how to do this? Many tks.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: Date(),
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek', 
            defaultTimedEventDuration:'01:00:00',
            dragScroll: false,
            eventDurationEditable: false,
            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            droppable: false,
            editable: false,
            eventStartEditable: false,
            eventLimit: false, 

       })
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

Does [Disable event creation on Weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397267/disable-event-creation-on-weekends) match your problem ?

The [select function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-method) gives the ability to prevent default click/selection behavior on the calendar.

Comment: Yes, I believe it will works but how can I disable drag n drop and limit the event duration at 1 hour on click in new event creation?